# Can't pass data through pendingIntent in firebase-cloud-messaging

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I'm using `firebase-cloud-messaging` for push notification to my application. I wanted that when user clicks on notification it open **OpenWeb** class and an Intent open url.

### Sended data using PHP:

```php
$data = array("notification"=> array("title"=>"http://example.com/",
                                 "text"=>"This is a test msg!",
                                 "click_action"=>"OpenWeb"),
          "priority" => "high",
          "to"=>"/topics/main");
```

### MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("link",title);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.notification))
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

### OpenWeb.java

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getIntent.getStringExtra("link"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<activity android:name=".OpenWeb">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="OpenWeb" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I click on notification the activity starts and `getIntent.getStringExtra("link")` in `OpenWeb` is **null**. That means the **MyFirebaseMessagingService** class doesn't send the data to the activity.

What should I do to send the data on `OpenWeb` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is some problems with the code
1. in your php script you are not specifying any `"body"` but you are still calling `String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();` thats one Null pointer exception.

2.This click_action key will work only when the app is in Foreground, for all other case when the app is in Background and closed, it doesn't work.

3.you need to set flags to start a new activity so `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

so if pending intent is firing youre ending up with an npe due to reason number 2, now you can do around this by sending data messages instead of the firebase sdk handling your notifications and then it will hallways be `NONNULL`

okay firebase has two types of messages

1. Push messages which are handled by the firebase SDK and that is messages that you set the title and the body and other factors but you cannot send custom data

> data masseages has to be key-value pairs though.

as an example you want to send some data with your notification that the client app will handle for example you are sending some news about a sports match so you can create a node in JSON format saying

```
data: { 
coolNews: "Some Cool News1",
coolNews2: "Some really cool news2"
}
```

and then you can call `remoteMessage.getData().get("coolNews");`

however be careful because if you send the following JSON

```
Notification:{
to: //UserToken , 
title: "Some Title",
body: "Some body",
data: { 
coolNews: "Some Cool News1",
coolNews2: "Some really cool news2"
}}
```

The data payload will only be managed after the client open the notification, however if you send the whole notification json as a data payload and you handle everything on the client side it will all be received at the same time. 
like the following:

```
 Notification:{
to: //UserToken 
data: { 
title: "Some Title",
body: "Some body",
coolNews: "Some Cool News1",
coolNews2: "Some really cool news2"
}}
```

and then in your `FirebaseMessageId` you can call `remotemessage.getData().get("title");` for the title and the same for all the others such as `body` and `coolNews`..

Now for the `BroadCast recevier` you can send broadcast through your `firebasemessagingId` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationBR.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble("key1",remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
        bundle.putDouble("key2",remoteMessage.getData().get("coolNews1"));
        ......
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and initiate a `broadcast class` and

> `DONT FORGET TO ADD TO YOUR MANIFEST!`

something like this...

```
public class NotificationBR extends BroadCastReciever {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent){
if(intent.getExtras() != null){
String key1 = intent.getStringExtra("key1");
......
}
//Then you can use intent to send it to whichever activity you want

Intent sendToActivity = new Intent(ctx, Activity.class);


 sendToActivity.putExtras(someBundle) //Containing your strings you want to pass to activity, you can also use sendToActivity.putStringExtra("Some values")


 startActivity(sendToActivity);
```

and thats it .

sorry about the typos..

Comment: could you explain more about data messages or broadcast receiver?

Comment: @Daniel check it out brother and accept the answer if you found it useful.